# What's a good use for an SSD that's too small to hold Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, ssd

I purchased a 32gb SSD (Solid State Drive) and didn't do enough homework before buying it.  I installed Windows 7 on it, but a few Windows Updates later, I have about 1 GB free.  Needless to say, that will get used up in a hurry.  I have a 1 TB platter hard drive also.

Since a 32gb SSD is too small to keep using as my boot drive, are there things I can do with the SSD to get a performance gain?  For example, should I keep my Windows Swap File on the SSD?

Thanks!

-Mike

Comment: Are you sure your Win7 installation in 31GB in size? Have you maybe not moved your User folder to a different drive?

Comment: Here's the current breakdown of my root folders on the SSD... Windows: 15gb, Program Files (x86 + 64 bit): 2gb, Users: 70mb

Answer (score 7):

Page file is a great idea. I'd also use it for programs that access the disk frequently.

Although I'm curious as to why you filled a 32GB drive with just a Windows 7 install. My clean install with updates came to around 10GB. I'm assuming you installed a bunch of programs on there as well? You could try installing all programs to a separate disk and leave the SSD as the OS drive.

Comment: I agree with this answer, I myself have a 40GB Intel X25-V SSD and the only programs I have installed on it are my frequently used ones like Office, etc. Games and everything else are spread across my harddrives. My SSD usage is 13.9GB free.

Answer (score 1):

32GB is too small for a useful XP SP3 installation as well, so I would guess that those small SSDs are intended to be used for Linux, like on the original netbooks.

Comment: Why would you install XP? It doesn't support TRIM.

Comment: @brandon927: TRIM support is recent (and very recent for Linux).  The original netbooks came out three years ago, and they had small SSDs and Linux or XP operating systems - before TRIM.

Comment: This is true. I just don't think its sensible to put XP on an SSD, thats just my preference I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest pairing it with a regular drive and using it for a separate data hard drive...